# Getting around truncated "ps"

Tags: solaris

I'm trying to write a script that will find a particular process based on a keyword, extract the PID, then kill it using the found PID.

The problem I'm having in Solaris is that, because the "ps" results are truncated, the search based on the keyword won't work because the keyword is part of the section (past 80 characters) that is truncated.

I read that you can use "/usr/ucb/ps awwx" to get something more than 80 characters, but as of Solaris 10, this needs to be run from root, and I can't avoid that restriction in my script.

Does anyone have any suggestions for getting that PID? The first 80 characters are too generic to search for (part of a java command).

Thanks.

Comment: I can run `/usr/ucb/ps awwx` without being root on Solaris 10: (uname -r says "5.10")

Comment: I too can run it as non-root (5.10 here). And i observe that ps axww output the already truncated lines (no more than ps -eoargs). So apparently it's not possible to squeeze more from this whatever the approach.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect (see my reply). Please post your script to figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: The `ps awwx` command also works on Mac OS X 10.9, as Darwin is Unix too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You assumption about ps behavior is incorrect. Even while you aren't logged as root, "/usr/ucb/ps -ww" doesn't truncate arguments for processes you own, i.e. for processes you can kill which are the only one you are interested in.

```
$ cat /etc/release
                    Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 s10x_u9wos_14a X86
     Copyright (c) 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 11 August 2010
$ id
uid=1000(jlliagre) gid=1000(jlliagre)
$ /usr/ucb/ps | grep abc
  2035 pts/3    S  0:00 /bin/ksh ./abc aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb
$ /usr/ucb/ps -ww | grep abc
  2035 pts/3    S  0:00 /bin/ksh ./abc aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
```

Comment: Note that in solaris 11, /usr/ucb became an "optional component" that you can choose to install.  An alternative (only available in solaris 10+) is pargs -l <pid>

Answer (score 15):

This works for me, at least on Joyent SmartMachine:

```
/usr/ucb/ps auxwwww
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest `pgrep` and `pkill` - http://www.opensolarisforum.org/man/man1/pkill.html - instead.

#### Edit 0:

How about this ugly `procfs` hack instead:

```
~$ for f in /proc/[0-9]*/cmdline; do if grep -q --binary-files=text KEYWORD $f; \
 > then l=`dirname $f`;p=`basename $l`; echo "killing $p"; kill $p; fi; done
```

I'm sure there's a shorter incantation for this but my shell-fu is a bit rusty.
Disclaimers: only tested in `bash` on Linux, would probably match itself too.

Comment: My script initially used pgrep, and I just tested it again, and it still hits the limit. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Yeah, I used the command "pkill -f keyword" and the process is still there.

Comment: That probably means you aren't allowed to kill the process because you do not own it.

Answer (score 2):

pargs will help here. though you'll have to iterate through all of the running procs which is a little annoying. but this will at least show you all of a procs arguments when ps would truncate them.

```
user@machine:(/home/user)> pargs 23097
23097:  /usr/bin/bash ./test.sh aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbb
argv[0]: /usr/bin/bash
argv[1]: ./test.sh
argv[2]: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
argv[3]: bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
argv[4]: ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

Comment: "pargs" is actually worst as a workaround. When "ps" truncates arguments, i.e. when you haven't sufficient privileges to see all of them (typically you don't own the process), "pargs" refuse to display any of them at all.

Comment: @noisesolo was asking about how to **find and kill** a process so I assume he is looking for a process that he has permission to kill/inspect args.

Comment: Awesome! This is the only solution that worked for me. `ps auxwwww` still only show 80 chars for the argument string

Comment: Great! I can make a handy script out of this in no time.

Answer (score 2):

```
ps "whatever your options" | cat
```

Works for me; trying to fool `ps` that `stdout` is not a `tty`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember exactly about solaris and i don't have an access to it now, only tomorrow, but in any case it's better to order the fields you want — simplifies parsing.

```
ps -o pid,args
```

If the output is truncated, maybe setting the column name to long string shall help.

Comment: This is great advice, but my process name is still too long (I'm looking for a keyword at the end of a long java command). Thanks though!

Comment: As i've mentioned before, probably it's already truncated by system, so it won't be possible altogether. I've checked a manual online about what's printed with -o args, it's stated that "The Solaris implementation limits the string to 80 characters". Probably in /proc it shall be the same.

Comment: I was just on a Solaris 11 system with no /usr/ucb/ps so I came to this page. ps -edalf -o pid,args printed out full command lines for me so this solved my problem. So is not always truncated.

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/ucb/ps -auxww | grep <processname> or <PID>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the `-w` option (twice for unlimited width):

```
$ ps -w -w -A -o pid,cmd
```

Comment: Not with Solaris regular ps: "ps: illegal option -- w",
"ps: illegal option -- w",
"ps: unknown output format: -o cmd"