# Unix Command output is curtailed

Tags: unix, solaris

I am trying to execute command

```
ps-ef | grep java
```

The output of this command is getting curtailed and I am not able to understand which process is it actually. So is there any way I can get the complete output and not the curtailed output?

For example output I receive when I execute the above command:

```
root 14018 13922   0   Nov 23 ?         381:00 java -D[Standalone] -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -d64 -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX
```

Now from the above output I am unable to know which process is this.

Comment: You know the PID and PPID, so is it the trouble that there are too many not-very-interesting options to Java and that's preventing you from seeing the important options that really identify what it's doing?  You can poke around the manual for `ps` to see if there's a way to get the full command line, but you may be out of luck there, too.  You may have to poke around `/proc/14018` to find out what the full command line is.  At least, that would be the last resort on Linux.  I'm not sure if the Solaris `/proc` file system is as informative.

Comment: Not a programming Q but dupe https://superuser.com/q/159606/ https://superuser.com/q/148271/ (both migrated) https://stackoverflow.com/q/4892516/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3934/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296560/ and for Java also consider `jps`

Comment: You might try `COLUMNS=10000 ps -ef | grep java `

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -eo pid,user,comm | grep java
```

Answer (score -1):

solaris 11 command

ps auxwww

This prints the complete length of the command.

Answer (score -1):

Try Below answer

```
echo "$(ps afx)"
```